# firefox pinned tabs/app tabs

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

I want to move the pinned tabs so that they are on the right side of the tab bar.

Is there a separate bar for the pinned tabs?

If so, how can I either move the "pinned tab bar" so that it stays to the right, relative to the normal tab bar?

Does anyone have any thoughts or code snippets so that I can manipulate the pinned tabs?

Comment: Are you writing a Firefox extension? If so, you should tag your question as [tag:firefox-addon]. Otherwise, please clarify your context.

Answer (score 0):

It's all done using relative positioning.  If you wanted everything to line up to the right you'll have to essentially rewrite this function, `_positionPinnedTabs` see it here in the source code: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml#3179

With a function like `_positionPinnedTabs` using `MozMarginEnd` (in the tab box case) instead of `MozMarginStart` you could create the right hand side space for the tabs.  Then you'd just need to position the tabs correctly in that space. Sorry it's not easier :)